# Google Maps API v3 - Custom Info box

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working my way through the Google Maps API and have the following thusfar:

```
var infowindow = null;

$(document).ready(function () { initialize();  });

function initialize() {

    var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(39.828175, -98.5795);

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: centerMap,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    setMarkers(map, sites);
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "loading..."
        });

    var bikeLayer = new google.maps.BicyclingLayer();
    bikeLayer.setMap(map);
}

var sites = [
    ['Mount Evans', 39.58108, -105.63535, 4, 'This is Mount Evans.'],
    ['Irving Homestead', 40.315939, -105.440630, 2, 'This is the Irving Homestead.'],
    ['Badlands National Park', 43.785890, -101.90175, 1, 'This is Badlands National Park'],
    ['Flatirons in the Spring', 39.99948, -105.28370, 3, 'These are the Flatirons in the spring.']
];



function setMarkers(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4]
        });

        var contentString = "Some content";

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //alert(this.html);
            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWpUm/) but it was not showing up.

So, the map supports multiple locations and info boxes, but the part I'm still very confused on is custom info boxes. I did some searching and saw [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955395/google-map-api-v3-how-to-get-list-of-custom-infoboxes-custom-overlays), but am having trouble understanding exactly how that works. So, let's say I have my `#map_canvas` map and then outside of that, I have an existing `#info` div (where I would like each info box loaded). So - the styles are not defined in the Google Maps API, it is an existing element that should take over as the info box.

Would anyone be able to nudge me along (or in this case, a shove would be great) to help me better understand how to do this? A quick screen shot of what I'm thinking can be found [here](http://i50.tinypic.com/denzg9.jpg). The dark red box on-top of the map is the target.

The custom markers and "active" state (the gold icon for the selected marker) are another challenge as well, but I haven't given up all hope on those just yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your fiddle had a couple of issues, here is a working verion: http://jsfiddle.net/LycXe/2/; the issues: 1. no jquery, but using "$". 2. The Google Maps API include needed to have &dummy=.js (per the documentation) so it would be recognized as javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its been a while but this should work.

When you create your markers, append whatever data you want to append to this marker.

Here is using the setMarkers function. Glad you added it (Was wondering where you have your loop)

In the html have your div to take this data like

```
 <div id="myDivID"></div>
```

In your js add a reference to it and insert html there

```
function setMarkers(map, markers) {
    var myContentDiv = document.getElementById('myDivID');//Reference to you DOM elem  

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var sites = markers[i];
        var siteLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(sites[1], sites[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: siteLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: sites[0],
            zIndex: sites[3],
            html: sites[4]
        });

        var contentString = "Some content";
        //marker.xtraData = 'SomeExtraData';//You can even add more data this way

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
            //alert(this.html);
            var myTemplate = '<h1>'+this.title+'<h1><p>'+this.html+'</p>';

            myContentDiv.innerHTML = myTemplate;//Inset this html inside link
            //infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            //infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
}
```

Depending on what you are doing you may also want to check out leaflet.  Its quite a bit faster than google maps on mobile browsers, and better than ios6 maps hehe.

Comment: Wow - that's awesome. I really appreciate you taking the time to write that out. Obviously looking at it now, it's "oh yeah, of course!" but wouldn't have got there without your help. Thanks again!

Comment: hehe, yeah. You were 99.9999999% there.  You had the alert and stuff all setup. Do checkout leaflet by the way if you have the chance, and you dont need the awesome features of public transportation, and street view.  If you just need a map, leaflet is FAST.